# Editable in a foreach loop?

Tags: glass-mapper

I know I've done this before but I just don't remember the proper syntax. I have a page where the model is `EventItem`, and `EventItem` has a list of `EventSpeakers` and each speaker has an image field. I want to make the images editable in Experience Editor.

```
@foreach (var person in Model.EventSpeakers){
    <div class="speaker">
        @Editable(??? => x.Speaker_Image)
    </div>
}
```

If I do `@Editable(x => x.Speaker_Image)`  that doesn't work, because `x` is an `EventItem` and not an `EventSpeaker`. How do I specify that `x` is `person` and not the page Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to do something like:

```
@foreach (var person in Model.EventSpeakers)
{
    <div class="speaker">
        @Editable(person, p => p.Speaker_Image)
    </div>
}
```

You just pass the item as the first parameter to the `@Editable`

Comment: Yes that's it, thank you!